# How much should I expect to pay for a PHP webhosting Service?

Tags: web-hosting

I recently purchased a domain name (GoDaddy).  After I finish developing the site, I was wondering how much I should expect to pay for a webhosting service?  In addition, I was wondering what are some good web hosting services?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want. I think pretty much any host will offer PHP, and I think for basic shared hosting, it's almost universally $5/month.

I've had good experience with [Bluehost](http://www.bluehost.com), although all the usual caveats for Shared Hosting apply (relatively slow, not able to install your own programs, they'll kick you if you use too many resources).

If you don't want shared hosting, [Linode](http://www.linode.com) is amazing, but it's probably more than you need (and $20/month is the minimum).

Also, I like [NearlyFreeSpeech](https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/). It's pay for what you use, so it's generally much cheaper than any other option (since if you actually used $5 worth of resources each month, a shared hosting company would kick you anyway). Downsides: They don't offer CPanel and last time I checked, they don't do SSL either.